# taggable_friends App Submision

Tags: facebook-wall

Since I am using the **Taggable friends API** to tag the specific friend so that private message can be send on the friend's facebook wall through tagging. Now while doing the app submission for taggable_friends facebook permission, the submission always gets reject. Please suggest so as to get the approval for this permission.

Answer (score 0):

You have to attach the apk for submission and write the proper steps for how to use your app and where you need the tag permission to come, attach the application screenshots also.
If your approval get rejected view the comment of the fb developer where your app is lacking fullfill that and then again submit for review.

Comment: Yes. Added all the mentioned details. They updated comments like "Using "taggable_friends" to count or visualize a user's friendlist is not approvable."